# Dual boot MacBook with Ubuntu 13.04, 32-bit

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, macbook

Please how can I dual boot Ubuntu 13.04 on my MacBook running Mac OS X 10.5.8 with the following specs:

Model Name: MacBook
  Model Identifier: MacBook5,2
  Processor Name: Intel Core 2 Duo
  Processor Speed: 2.13 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores: 2
  L2 Cache: 3MB
  Memory: 2GB
  Bus Speed:    1.07 GHz
  Boot ROM Version: MB52.0088.B05
  SMC Version (system): 1.38f5
  Serial Number (system): W89214SE9GU
  Hardware UUID:    D0110864-A751-56AF-8BB3-BBA03A9E93FA
  Sudden Motion Sensor:
  State:    Enabled

I enjoyed using Ubuntu on my Dell notebook, but I don't have it anymore plus I am new to Mac and would love to have Ubuntu running side by side with my MacBook. I would appreciate it greatly if anyone could assist me to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

You dual boot Ubuntu by using boot camp. Here is a video on how to use boot camp on your mac. [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3a9yhQ3JnBg)

Comment: A virtual machine is not the same as dual boot. Also, you're not explaining *how* to do this using Boot Camp.

Comment: @gertvdijk Good point on the VM. I didn't think I had to explain how to use boot camp, I thought is was common knowledge.